# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void shareMEUEnrollmentWithUsers(List<MEU_Enrollment__c>) from the type shareMEUEnrollment

Tags: apex, trigger

I have written an apex sharing class and trying to invoke it with a trigger but I am getting error
as "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void shareMEUEnrollmentWithUsers(List<MEU_Enrollment__c>) from the type shareMEUEnrollment." Why it is showing error?Please help.

```
trigger shareMEUEnrollmentTrigger1 on MEU_Enrollment__c (before insert, after insert, before update, after update) {
    if(trigger.isbefore || trigger.isafter){
        if(trigger.isinsert || trigger.isupdate){
        shareMEUEnrollment.shareMEUEnrollmentWithUsers(trigger.new);
```

Apex Class

```
public without sharing class shareMEUEnrollment {
    
    public static void shareMEUEnrollmentWithUsers(List<ID> recordId) {
        List<MEU_Enrollment__Share> enrolExistingSharingList = [select id from MEU_Enrollment__Share where id in : recordId and RowCause = 'Manual'];
        if(enrolExistingSharingList.size() > 0) {
            delete enrolExistingSharingList ;  
        }
        
        List<MEU_Enrollment__c> enrolList = [select id, Owner.Id from MEU_Enrollment__c where id in : recordId ];
        Set<Id> OwnerIdSet = new Set<Id>();
        
        for(MEU_Enrollment__c l : enrolList) {
            OwnerIdSet.add(l.OwnerId);
        }
        
        List<User> userIdList = [select id, contact.Id from user where id in : OwnerIdSet];
        List<id> contactIdSet = new List<id>();
        Map<id,id> contactUserMap = new Map<id,id>();
        
        for(User u : userIdList) {
            contactIdSet.add(u.Contact.Id);
            contactUserMap.put(u.id, u.Contact.Id);
        }
        
        Map<Id, Id> enrolContactMap = new Map<Id,Id>();
        
        for(MEU_Enrollment__c l : enrolList) {
            enrolContactMap.put(l.id, contactUserMap.get(l.Owner.Id));
        }
        
        List<Contact> agentContactsList = [select id, Account.ParentId from Contact where id in :contactIdSet ];
        Set<Id> parentAccountId = new Set<Id>();
        Map<Id,Id> contactAccountMap = new Map<Id, Id>();
        for(Contact con : agentContactsList ) {
            if(con.Account.ParentId!=null) {
                parentAccountId.add(con.Account.ParentId);
                contactAccountMap.put(con.id,con.Account.ParentId);
            }
        }
        
        Map<id, List<Contact>> accountAdminsMap = new Map<Id,List<Contact>>();
        List<Contact> adminsList = new List<Contact>();
        Set<Id> adminContactId = new Set<Id>();
        
        for(Contact c : [select id,AccountId from Contact where accountid in : parentAccountId]) {
            adminsList.add(c);
            accountAdminsMap.put(c.AccountId, adminsList);
            adminContactId.add(c.id);
        }   
        
        Map<id,List<Contact>> enrolAdminsMap = new Map<Id,List<Contact>>();
        
        for(MEU_Enrollment__c l : enrolList) {
            if(accountAdminsMap.get(contactAccountMap.get(enrolContactMap.get(l.id)))!=null)
                enrolAdminsMap.put(l.id, accountAdminsMap.get(contactAccountMap.get(enrolContactMap.get(l.id))));
        }
        
        Map<id,id> adminContactUserMap = new Map<id,id>();   
        //map to store the mapping of admin contact id and corresponding user id
        for(User u : [select id,contactid from user where contactid in : adminContactId]) {
            adminContactUserMap.put(u.ContactId,u.id);
        } 
        
        List<MEU_Enrollment__Share> enrolShareNew = new List<MEU_Enrollment__Share>();
        
        for(MEU_Enrollment__c l : enrolList) {
            
            if(enrolAdminsMap.get(l.id) != null) {
                
                for(Contact c : enrolAdminsMap.get(l.id)) {
                    
                    if(adminContactUserMap.get(c.id) != null ) {
                        
                        MEU_Enrollment__Share ls = new MEU_Enrollment__Share();
                        ls.ParentId = l.id ;
                        ls.AccessLevel = 'Edit' ;
                        ls.UserorGroupId = adminContactUserMap.get(c.id);
                        enrolShareNew.add(ls);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        System.debug('enrolShareNew : ' + enrolShareNew);
        System.debug('Total enrolShareNew : ' + enrolShareNew.size());
        
        try {
            Database.insert(enrolShareNew);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.debug('Exceptiom is " '+ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void shareMEURecords(List<ID> leadIds) {
        try {
            //Share enrollment records to lead owner and respective GA Admins 
            List<MEU_Enrollment__Share> enrollShareList = new List<MEU_Enrollment__Share>();
            enrollShareList.addAll( prepareEnrollmentShare(leadIds) );
            
            if(!enrollShareList.isEmpty() && enrollShareList.size() > 0) {
                Database.insert(enrollShareList);
            }
        }
        catch(exception e) {
            String commentStr = 'Line Number and Exception Message : \n';
            commentStr = commentStr + 'Line Number - ' + e.getLineNumber() + '\n';
            commentStr = commentStr + 'Error Message : ' + e.getMessage();
            
            Apex_Debug_Log__c logRecord = new Apex_Debug_Log__c();
            logRecord.Class__c = 'shareMEUEnrollment';
            logRecord.Comment__c = commentStr;
            logRecord.Message__c = 'Stack Trace Error Message - ' + e.getStackTraceString();
            logRecord.Method__c = 'execute';
            logRecord.Status__c = 'Error';
            
            insert logRecord;
            system.debug('@@@shareMEUEnrollment - shareMEURecords - Error - commentStr : ' + commentStr);
        }
    }
    
    public static List<MEU_Enrollment__Share> prepareEnrollmentShare(List<ID> leadIds) {
        System.debug('@@@shareMEUEnrollment - prepareEnrollmentShare - Method Entry - leadIds : ' + leadIds);
        
        List<Group> queueList = [ Select Id, Name, DeveloperName From Group Where Type = 'Queue' And DeveloperName = 'CMC_Internal_Queue' Limit 1];
        String cmcInternalQueueId = queueList.get(0).Id;
        
        MEU_Enrollment__Share enrShare = new MEU_Enrollment__Share();
        Set<Id> enrollmentIds = new Set<Id>();
        Map<Id, String> queueMap = new Map<Id, String>();
        Map<Id, Id> mapLeadOwnerIds = new Map<Id, Id>();
        Map<Id, Id> mapLeadGaAdminQueueIds = new Map<Id, Id>();
        List<MEU_Enrollment__Share> enrollShareList = new List<MEU_Enrollment__Share>();
        List<MEU_Enrollment__c> enrollmentList = new List<MEU_Enrollment__c>();
        
        List<Lead> leadList = [Select Id, Name, OwnerId, (Select Id, Name, Lead__c, OwnerId From MEU_Enrollments__r)
                               From lead Where Id In :leadIds];
        
        if(leadList.size() > 0) {
            for(Lead ld : leadList) {
                mapLeadOwnerIds.put(ld.Id, ld.OwnerId);
                enrollmentList.addAll(ld.MEU_Enrollments__r);
            }
        }
        System.debug('@@@shareMEUEnrollment - prepareEnrollmentShare - enrollmentList : ' + enrollmentList);
        
        //Get the GA Admin Queue Id
        mapLeadGaAdminQueueIds.putAll( getGaAdminQueues(leadList, mapLeadOwnerIds) );
        System.debug('@@@shareMEUEnrollment - prepareEnrollmentShare - mapLeadGaAdminQueueIds : ' + mapLeadGaAdminQueueIds);
        
        if(enrollmentList.size() > 0) {
            for(MEU_Enrollment__c enr : enrollmentList) {
                enrollmentIds.add(enr.Id);
            }
        }
        
        //Delete all existing share records
        List<MEU_Enrollment__Share> existingEnrollShareList = [Select Id From MEU_Enrollment__Share Where ParentId In :enrollmentIds 
                                                               and RowCause = 'Manual' And UserorGroupId <> :cmcInternalQueueId];
        System.debug('@@@shareMEUEnrollment - prepareEnrollmentShare - existingEnrollShareList : ' + existingEnrollShareList);
        if(!existingEnrollShareList.isEmpty() && existingEnrollShareList.size() > 0) {
            delete existingEnrollShareList;
        }
        
        //Prepare new enrollment share list
        if(enrollmentList.size() > 0) {
            for(MEU_Enrollment__c enr : enrollmentList) {
                System.debug('@@@shareMEUEnrollment - Enrollment Name : ' + enr.Name);
                
                //Share the record to Lead Owner
                enrShare = new MEU_Enrollment__Share();
                enrShare.ParentId = enr.Id;
                enrShare.AccessLevel = 'Edit';
                enrShare.RowCause = 'Manual';
                enrShare.UserorGroupId = mapLeadOwnerIds.get(enr.Lead__c);
                enrollShareList.add(enrShare);
                System.debug('@@@shareMEUEnrollment - Share Record with Leads current owner - ' + enr.Name + ' - ' + enrShare);
                
                //Share the record to GA Admin (while lead owner changed to Agent)
                if(mapLeadGaAdminQueueIds.containsKey(enr.Lead__c) && String.isNotBlank(mapLeadGaAdminQueueIds.get(enr.Lead__c)) ) {
                    enrShare = new MEU_Enrollment__Share();
                    enrShare.ParentId = enr.Id;
                    enrShare.AccessLevel = 'Edit';
                    enrShare.RowCause = 'Manual';
                    enrShare.UserorGroupId = mapLeadGaAdminQueueIds.get(enr.Lead__c);
                    
                    if(! enrollShareList.contains(enrShare)) {
                        enrollShareList.add(enrShare);
                    }
                    System.debug('@@@shareMEUEnrollment - (To Admin) Share Record for ' + enr.Name + ' - ' + enrShare);
                }
            }
        }
        
        System.debug('@@@shareMEUEnrollment - prepareEnrollmentShare - Method Exit - enrollShareList : ' + enrollShareList);
        return enrollShareList;
    }
    
    public static Map<Id, Id> getGaAdminQueues(List<Lead> leadList, Map<Id, Id> mapLeadOwnerIds) {
        String agencyName = '';
        Set<String> queueNameSet = new Set<String>();
        Map<String, String> agencyQueueNameMap = new Map<String, String>();
        Map<String, String> agencyQueueIdMap = new Map<String, String>();
        Map<String, String> userAgencyMap = new Map<String, String>();
        Map<Id, Id> mapLeadGaAdminQueueIds = new Map<Id, Id>();
        
        List<User> userList = [Select Id, Name, Department From User Where Id In :mapLeadOwnerIds.values()];
        
        if(!userList.isEmpty() && userList.size() > 0) {
            for(User u : userList) {
                userAgencyMap.put(u.Id, u.Department);
            }
        }
        
        List<Agency_Queue_Detail__mdt> agencyQueueList = [Select Label, DeveloperName, Queue_Label__c, Queue_Name__c
                                                          From Agency_Queue_Detail__mdt
                                                          Where Is_Agency_Active__c = true ];
        
        //system.debug('agencyQueueList : '+agencyQueueList);
        
        for(Agency_Queue_Detail__mdt aq : agencyQueueList){
            if(String.isNotBlank(aq.Queue_Name__c)){
                queueNameSet.add(aq.Queue_Name__c);
                agencyQueueNameMap.put(aq.Label, aq.Queue_Name__c);
            }
        }
        
        List<Group> grpDetailList = [ Select Id, Name, DeveloperName From Group Where Type = 'Queue' AND DeveloperName In :queueNameSet ];
        for(Group grp : grpDetailList){
            agencyQueueIdMap.put(grp.DeveloperName, grp.Id);
        }
        
        for(Lead ld : leadList) {
            agencyName = '';
            agencyName = userAgencyMap.get(ld.OwnerId);
            mapLeadGaAdminQueueIds.put(ld.Id, agencyQueueIdMap.get(agencyQueueNameMap.get(agencyName)));
        }
        
        return mapLeadGaAdminQueueIds;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void shareMEUEnrollmentWithUsers(List<ID> recordId) {
```

Is asking for a `List<Id>`, but:

```
    shareMEUEnrollment.shareMEUEnrollmentWithUsers(trigger.new);
```

Is giving it a `List<MEU_Enrollment__c>`.

You'll need to change your trigger code:

```
    shareMEUEnrollment.shareMEUEnrollmentWithUsers(new List<Id>(trigger.newMap.keySet()));
```

Or your handler:

```
public static void shareMEUEnrollmentWithUsers(sObject[] records) {
```

Which would require significant refactoring.

It's important to note that `before insert` is a waste of time, as there are no record Ids (the records aren't inserted yet), and you're probably wasting a lot of CPU time using both `before` and `after` triggers. Just use the `after` triggers.